# Bar chart in oracle apex 5 shows label names as Group

Tags: oracle-apex

Please see the picture below. This simple bar chart that uses a group by in the sql shows label as "Group 6". Is there any attribute I need to set to show only labels and not these Group names.

[Apex 5.1 bar chart issue groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZwKb.jpg)

Any help appreciated

Comment: create view and select from your view

Comment: the sql gets pageitem values dynamically, so cant put it in a view